# What would +- do as an operator in c#

Tags: c#

I have researched into this extensively, but cannot seem to find anything in its regard.

If I was to use an if statement as a validation and needed to write something along these lines:

```
if(split[lengthsplit + 1] == "=" && split[lengthsplit - 1] == "=")
```

Could I write the above as the following with the same result:

```
if(split[lengthsplit +- 1] == "=")
```

I cannot see the result of this and am wondering if in this case it would add a 1 and take it away or if it would try both scenarios first giving the ability to compress the validation down getting rid of the boolean operators to some degree.

If this is the case though perhaps I could use a split[lengthsplit+-] instead?

Comment: `x +- 1` == `x + -1` ==  `x-1`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was leaning towards just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could I write the above as the following with the same result

No you can't because this `lengthsplit +- 1` translates to `lengthsplit + (-1)` because the `-` here is considered a unary operator (and [unary operators have higher precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than the binary `+`).

Answer (score 1):

`lengthsplit +- 1` is `lengthsplit + (-1)` there is no "-+" or "+-" operator in "C#"

Comment: Great, thats along the lines I thought it would go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `+-` operator. The example you have provided is a perfect example of how not to use whitespace. If anything the + cancels itself out.